# Можно ли перехватывать команды из HTML страницы в WebView?

Tags: java, html, android, webview

Есть WebView, в него загружена страница HTML, в ней например ссылка или картинка. Могу ли я перехватить нажатие на картинку или ссылку и передать приложению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перехватывать изменения URL.
Для этого у WebViewClient нужно переопределить метод

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

или

```
shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
```

Перехватывать нажатия как-то, думаю ,можно, но не просто. Например установить у WebView onTouchListener, в котором определять каким-то образом, какой элемент находится по этим координатам.

UPD:
Как определить, какой элемент находится по заданным координатам:

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.elementFromPoint(x, y);");
```

Результат можно вернуть, встроив в WebView JavaScriptInterface